How to uninstall a dev package with Pipenv 2024.0.1?
I have some unnecessary packages in the [dev-packages] section of my Pipfile and I cannot uninstall them with the latest Pipenv (2024.0.1). Uninstalling packages from the [packages] section of the Pipfile works fine.
I've tried all of pipenv uninstall packagename, pipenv uninstall --dev packagename, and pipenv uninstall -d packagename all to the same non-effect.
Here is the output when trying to uninstall python-docx:
% pipenv uninstall --dev python-docx
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success!
Uninstalling python-docx...

pipenv uninstall --dev python-docx  8.97s user 1.07s system 84% cpu 11.921 total

Nothing changes in the Pipfile. The Pipfile.lock has some extraneous changes but still contains the python-docx package.
% git diff Pipfile.lock             
diff --git a/Pipfile.lock b/Pipfile.lock
index 5b761ce..b3ad052 100644
--- a/Pipfile.lock
+++ b/Pipfile.lock
@@ -296,14 +296,6 @@
             "markers": "python_version >= '3.5'",
             "version": "==3.6"
         },
-        "importlib-metadata": {
-            "hashes": [
-                "sha256:4805911c3a4ec7c3966410053e9ec6a1fecd629117df5adee56dfc9432a1081e",
-                "sha256:f238736bb06590ae52ac1fab06a3a9ef1d8dce2b7a35b5ab329371d6c8f5d2cc"
-            ],
-            "markers": "python_version < '3.10'",
-            "version": "==7.0.1"
-        },
         "jinja2": {
             "hashes": [
                 "sha256:7d6d50dd97d52cbc355597bd845fabfbac3f551e1f99619e39a35ce8c370b5fa",
@@ -657,14 +649,6 @@
             "markers": "python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5'",
             "version": "==1.26.18"
         },
-        "zipp": {
-            "hashes": [
-                "sha256:0e923e726174922dce09c53c59ad483ff7bbb8e572e00c7f7c46b88556409f31",
-                "sha256:84e64a1c28cf7e91ed2078bb8cc8c259cb19b76942096c8d7b84947690cabaf0"
-            ],
-            "markers": "python_version >= '3.8'",
-            "version": "==3.17.0"
-        },
         "zope.event": {
             "hashes": [
                 "sha256:2832e95014f4db26c47a13fdaef84cef2f4df37e66b59d8f1f4a8f319a632c26",
(END)


It seems that you have to run pipenv uninstall --all-dev to remove all dev packages first, and then reinstall those you need.
